# Adding 2 sliding menus to an activity

Tags: android, android-activity, menu, fragment, sliding

I have an activity, where using the Sliding Menu library, i try to create 2 sliding menus.
This is the code i tried:

```
 FragmentTransaction t = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_NONE);
    menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    menu.setMenu(R.layout.tutorial_layout);
    rightSlide = new HelpFragment();
    t.replace(R.id.slidingList2, rightSlide);
    t.commit();
    menu.setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.log_history);
    leftSlide = new LogHistory();
    t.replace(R.id.loghistorycon, leftSlide);
    t.commit();
```

Now i get a ANR error, and Logcat says, that the FragmentTransaction t, has already been commited.
I looked at the example from: github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu and it allows him to do 2 commit's:

```
 setContentView(R.layout.content_frame);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.content_frame, new SampleListFragment())
    .commit();

    getSlidingMenu().setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.menu_frame_two);
    getSlidingMenu().setSecondaryShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadowright);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.menu_frame_two, new SampleListFragment())
    .commit();
```

What am I doing wrong? i just can't see the difference

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14909076/967548

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your above code as below

```
 FragmentTransaction t = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_NONE);
    menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    menu.setMenu(R.layout.tutorial_layout);
    rightSlide = new HelpFragment();
    t.replace(R.id.slidingList2, rightSlide);
    t.commit();
    t = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    menu.setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.log_history);
    leftSlide = new LogHistory();
    t.replace(R.id.loghistorycon, leftSlide);
    t.commit();
```

For a `FragmentTransaction`, you can have only one commit. In your code you created a `FragmentTransaction` object and called commit once for `rightSlide`. So t is not usable for transactions anymore. So you have create another `FragmentTransaction` as I have done in the above code. I hope this will work for you.

Comment: thanks, this is a huge step forward for me, it works, but now i have another question. I have 2 buttons, one for each menu, how to I select which one should the first button open, and then the second?
I have tried:

       menu.showMenu();     
       menu.toggle();

for first one, and for the second:

       menu.showSecondaryMenu();
        menu.toggle();

Comment: @rosualin your second question is confusing. but will say you answer. when you have two buttons, append one slider to one button i.e. handle first button click for first sliding menu and second for second sliding menu.

Comment: yes, i understood that, i made clickListeners for the buttons, and how can i select which of those 2 sliding menu's to open with menu.toggle() ?

Comment: yes you need to use menu.toggle() for swapping the current state.

Comment: menu.toggle just opens the first sliding menu, and then, on the second command closes the first sliding menu. I have tried with showSecondaryMenu(), and showMenu();, but still, both buttons just show me the first menu

Comment: @rosualin What the idea I have explained you. don't know more about this sliding menu.

Comment: thanks a lot, i will keep on searching, and i will post the answer when I'll find it, also i will accept your answer after I figure out what is wrong, because the answer you gave me, is correct, but i still have the other issue, and i think more people will look over the question if it's not answered. Thank you again

Comment: I needed to put: menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT); so that it could have 2 menus

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22881/discussion-between-nagaraj436-and-rosu-alin)

Comment: @TNR, i'm facing problem in sliding. i.e if i add showsecondarymenu() instead of toggle i'm getting blank. could you please help me

Answer (score 1):

@LLL
Following code is working Properly to me.i hope,it help u more...

```
    SlidingMenu slidingMenu  = getSlidingMenu();slidingMenu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
    slidingMenu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    slidingMenu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    slidingMenu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    slidingMenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_NONE);
    slidingMenu.setMenu(R.layout.profile);
    slidingMenu.setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.nextactivity);
    Button csButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.txtx);
    inside csButton onclick listener just need to call slidingMenu.showSecondaryMenu();
    and, Button csButton1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    inside csButton1 onclick listener just need to call slidingMenu.showMenu();
```