# Android slide menu that slide from both sides left and right

Tags: android, android-side-navigation

I'm trying to make sliding drawer menu like the one in the Facebook app. I navigated many questions [like this amazing one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657894/android-facebook-style-slide).
and found a lot of libraries but all of them slide from left to right or from right to left in different one. I want to make it slide from both sides, left to right and right to left via two buttons in the top bar. Can any one help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363082/how-to-android-slide-menu-that-slide-from-both-sides-left-and-right

Comment: You can look at https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/SlidingDrawer, which mekes it possible for you to slide from any side.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

this is the one I use and does exactly what you want:

[SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/)

You will have to implement the button feature yourself but it shouldn't be too hard!

EDIT:

An example:

```
SlidingMenu menuS = new SlidingMenu(this);
menuS.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
menuS.setMenu(R.layout.slideout_list);
menuS.setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.slideout_list2);
```

As the code shows you need to set the mode to LEFT_RIGHT and must specify a layout for both the left menu (setMenu()) and the right menu (setSecondaryMenu()) along with the other options specifying menu size and shadows etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The demo contains exactly what I want.

Comment: Ca you please suggest me how its working from left to right And in the same app from right to left.. exactly like Facebook... ??

Comment: But it only open slider from left side only not from right side .Please suggest for it

Answer (score 6):

Try this

https://github.com/srikanthgr/FacebookSlideOutmenu

implement this in to your project, This is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 5):

There is a branch for a right to left sliding menu of the jfeinstein's [SlidingMenu original](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) here: 
https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/tree/slidingright

Alternatively, there is Simon's implementation which has simple configurations for making the switch from **Left-to-Right** and **Right-to-Left** here: https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer. There is a simple example on the page.

Although, I'm not one to publicly voice an opinion, I find Simon's library a tad easier to use. ;-)

That being said, I don't, however, **take away absolutely** any credit from **jfeinstein** either. His library powers one of my better *selling* apps. :-)

Comment: Look into this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363082/how-to-android-slide-menu-that-slide-from-both-sides-left-and-right

Answer (score 5):

This question is now very old, but it has been built into Android now. So if people are searching and come across this post, hit up the Navigation Drawer section on the developer pages of Android.

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Comment: Looking for both sides. Not just left.

Answer (score 4):

Use this one, it's good for you :

```
abstract public class BaseSlideFragmentActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity implements IActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Utils.log(new Exception(), "[onCreate]");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getSlidingMenu().setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
    getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);

    setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_right);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.menuRight, new MenuRightFragment()).commit();

    getSlidingMenu().setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.menu_left);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.menuLeft, new MenuLeftFragment()).commit();

    getSlidingMenu().setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    getSlidingMenu().setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    getSlidingMenu().setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    setSlidingActionBarEnabled(false);
}

public Activity getActivity() {
    return this;
}

@Override
public MyApplication getApplicationContext() {
    return (MyApplication) super.getApplicationContext();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Utils.log(new Exception(), "[onOptionsItemSelected]");
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            toggle();
            return true;
        case R.id.setting:
            if (getSlidingMenu().isMenuShowing()) {
                toggle();
            }
            else {
                showSecondaryMenu();
            }
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    Utils.log(new Exception(), "[onCreateOptionsMenu]");
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_setting, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // setTitle(R.string.attach);
        // set the content view
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      // configure the Sliding right Menu
        SlidingMenu menuR = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menuR.setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT);
        menuR.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);



   //     menuR.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.abc_action_bar_default_height);

     // menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);right menu
        menuR.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.abc_action_bar_default_height);
        menuR.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        menuR.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
        menuR.setMenu(R.layout.right_menu_layout);


      // configure the Sliding left Menu
        SlidingMenu menuL = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menuL.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        menuL.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);


     //       menuL.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.abc_action_bar_default_height);

     // menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);left menu
        menuL.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.abc_action_bar_default_height);
        menuL.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        menuL.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
        menuL.setMenu(R.layout.left_menu_layout);


    }
```

Comment: Can you fix your formatting please? Some of your indentation is off.